# Is it possible to render specific indexes in React native's VirtualizedList?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have this long VirtualizedList in my React Native project:

```
    <VirtualizedList
        horizontal
        data={pages}
        pagingEnabled
        windowSize={2}
        initialNumToRender={3}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
        initialScrollIndex={page}
        onMomentumScrollEnd={onScrollEnd}
        getItemCount={data => data.length}
        keyExtractor={(_, i) => i + ''}
        getItemLayout={(_, index) => ({
            length: width,
            offset: width * index,
            index
        })}
        getItem={(_, index) => ({index})}
        renderItem={renderPage}
    />
```

Right now, it is rendering **3 items before** and **2 items after** the current page.

**My question is:**

Can you specify exactly which indexes should be rendered?

Because i have a header that lets the user jump to a specific index, and i can anticipate which index could be next.